# As an overseas company owner, what are my tax obligations to the UK?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, united-kingdom, foreign-income

I'm a dual resident of the UK and Country X for tax purposes. I'm not employed in the UK or Country X. However, I have a single company registered in Country X, which has regular income. The income goes to a bank in Country X.

My questions are:

- Do I have any tax obligations to the UK due to the income of my company that's registered in Country X?
- Would the type of the company (that's registered in Country X) being a sole proprietorship or an LLC make a difference here?

I would also appreciate any links to relevant sources.

Answer (score 2):

If you're a UK resident, it is likely that you're taxed on your *worldwide* income. So yes, you would have tax obligations in the UK. The type of the company *would* probably matter. I suggest you talk to a professional tax adviser proficient in the laws of both the countries and the tax treaty between them, if exists.